# What is Isabelle/HOL command for Compute in Coq?

Tags: coq, isabelle

Proof assistant Coq have `compute` command (and also `check` command for determination of the type) which returns the result of function application. Does Isabelle/HOL have similar command and how it is named?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isabelle has a "value" command that performs evaluation.

```
value "rev [1::nat,2,3]"
```

Isabelle then responds with:

```
"[Suc (Suc (Suc 0)), Suc (Suc 0), Suc 0]"
  :: "nat list"
```

(Quoted from https://lists.cam.ac.uk/pipermail/cl-isabelle-users/2007-October/msg00008.html)